# Is the set of bounded operators a linear space?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, operator-theory

Let $H_1$ and $H_2$ two Hilbert Spaces. Is the set of bounded operators from $H_1$ to $H_2$ a linear space?
My first feeling is that it is true, but I don’t know how to prove it. Could anyone help or give me some references?

Thank you!

Comment: You prove it by definition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $X$ and $Y$ be vector spaces over the same field $F$, and let $\mbox{ Hom }(X, Y)$ denote the set of all the linear transformations $T \colon X \rightarrow Y$, that is, let
$$
\mbox{ Hom } (X, Y) \colon= \big\{ \, T \colon X \rightarrow Y \, \colon \, T \mbox{ is linear } \, \big\}.
$$
Then $\mbox{ Hom } (X, Y)$ is also a vector space over the field $F$ under the operations $+_{ \mbox{ Hom } (X, Y) }$ and scalar multiplication defined as follows:

Let $S, T \in \mbox{ Hom } (X, Y)$. Then $S \colon X \rightarrow Y$ and $T \colon X \rightarrow Y$ are both linear transformations. Now let $S +_{ \mbox{ Hom } (X, Y) } T \colon X \rightarrow Y$ be the mapping defined by 
$$
\left( S +_{ \mbox{ Hom } (X, Y) } T \right) (x) \colon= S(x) +_Y T(x) \ \mbox{ for } x \in X. \tag{Formula for Sum}
$$
We can easily show that the mapping $S +_{ \mbox{ Hom } (X, Y) } T \colon X \rightarrow Y$ is a linear transformation.

Now let $T \in \mbox{ Hom }(X, Y)$ and let $\alpha \in F$. Then the mapping $\alpha T \colon X \rightarrow Y$ defined by the formula
$$
\big( \alpha T \big)(x) \colon= \alpha T(x) \ \mbox{ for } x \in X. \tag{Formula for Scalar Multiple}
$$
The scalar multiplication on the right-hand-side of this formula of course takes place in our vector space $Y$.

Under the above operations of vector addition and scalar multiplication $\mbox{ Hom }(X, Y)$ is a vector space over $F$.

[ If you want a detailed proof, then please contact me directly.]

Now let $X$ and $Y$ be normed spaces, either both real or both complex. Then a linear transformation $T \colon X \rightarrow Y$ is said to be a *bounded linear operator* if there exists a real number $\lambda_T$ such that 
$$
\big\lVert T(x) \big\rVert_Y \leq \lambda_T \lVert x \rVert_X \ \mbox{ for all } x \in X. \tag{Definition of Boundedness}
$$
Such a real number $\lambda_T$, if it exists, is of course non-negative. And, if $X \neq \left\{ \mathbf{0}_X \right\}$, then in this case the set
$$
\left\{ \, \frac{ \big\lVert T(x) \big\rVert_Y  }{ \lVert x \rVert_X } \, \colon \, x \in X, x \neq \mathbf{0}_X \, \right\} \tag{A}
$$
is a non-empty bounded subset of $\mathbb{R}$; in fact $\lambda_T$ is an upper bound of this set.

Let $B(X, Y)$ denote the set of all the bounded linear operators $T \colon X \rightarrow Y$, where $X$ and $Y$ are normed spaces, either both real or both complex. Then $B(X, Y)$ is a subspace of $\mbox{ Hom }(X, Y)$.

The zero mapping $\mathbf{0}_{ \mbox{ Hom }(X, Y) } \colon X \rightarrow Y$ defined by 
$$
\mathbf{0}_{ \mbox{ Hom }(X, Y) } (x) \colon= \mathbf{0}_Y \ \mbox{ for all } x \in X
$$
is a bounded linear operator as per (Definition of Boundedness) above.

If $S, T \in B(X, Y)$. Then there exist real numbers $\lamba_S$ and $\lambda_T$ such that 
$$
\big\lVert T(x) \big\rVert_Y \leq \lambda_T \lVert x \rVert_X \ \mbox{ for all } x \in X,
$$
and 
$$
\big\lVert T(x) \big\rVert_Y \leq \lambda_T \lVert x \rVert_X \ \mbox{ for all } x \in X.
$$
Therefore for all $x \in X$, we obtain
$$
\begin{align}
\left\lVert \left( S +_{ \mbox{ Hom }(X, Y) } T \right)(x) \right\rVert_Y &= \left\lVert S(x) +_Y T(x) \right\rVert_Y \\
&\leq \big\lVert S(x) \big\rVert_Y + \big\lVert T(x) \big\rVert_Y \\
&\leq \lambda_S \lVert x \rVert_X + \lambda_T \lVert x \rVert_X \\
&= \left( \lambda_S + \lambda_T \right) \lVert x \rVert_X.
\end{align}
$$
Thus we obtain
$$
\left\lVert \left( S +_{ \mbox{ Hom }(X, Y) } T \right)(x) \right\rVert_Y  \leq \left( \lambda_S + \lambda_T \right) \lVert x \rVert_X \ \mbox{ for all } x \in X, \tag{1}
$$
which shows that $S +_{ \mbox{ Hom }(X, Y) } T \colon X \rightarrow Y$ is a bounded linear operator, that is, $S +_{ \mbox{ Hom }(X, Y) } T \in B(X, Y)$.

And, if $T \in B(X, Y)$ and $\alpha$ is a scalar, then from (Definition of Boundedness) we obtain for any $x \in X$,
$$
\begin{align}
\big\lVert \big( \alpha T \big)(x) \big\rVert_Y &= \big\lVert \alpha T(x) \big\rVert \\
&= \lvert \alpha \rvert \, \lVert T(x) \rVert_Y \\
&\leq \lvert \alpha \rvert \, \lambda_T \lVert x \rVert_X.
\end{align}
$$
Thus we have a real number $\lvert \alpha \rvert \times \lambda_T$ such that 
$$
\big\lVert \big( \alpha T \big)(x)  \big\rVert_Y \leq \big( \lvert \alpha \rvert  \, \lambda_T \big) \times  \lVert x \rVert_X \ \mbox{ for all } x \in X. \tag{2} 
$$
Thus $\alpha T \colon X \rightarrow Y$ is also a bounded linear operator, that is, $\alpha T \in B(X, Y)$.

Thus the set $B(X, Y)$ is a subset of $\mbox{ Hom }(X, Y)$, and this subset  contains the zero vector of the vector space $\mbox{ Hom }(X, Y)$ and is also closed under the operations of vector addition and scalar multiplication for $\mbox{ Hom }(X, Y)$. Therefore $B(X, Y)$ is a (vector)  subspace of $\mbox{ Hom }(X, Y)$.

For any $T \in B(X, Y)$, let us define 
$$
\big\lVert T \big\rVert_{B(X, Y)} \colon= \sup \left\{ \, \frac{ \big\lVert T(x) \big\rVert_Y  }{ \lVert x \rVert_X } \, \colon \, x \in X, x \neq \mathbf{0}_X \, \right\} \tag{Definition of Norm}
$$
Then we have the inequality
$$
\big\lVert T(x) \big\rVert_Y \leq \big\lVert T \big\rVert_{B(X, Y)} \, \lVert x \rVert_X  \ \mbox{ for all } x \in X. \tag{Norm Inequality} 
$$
And, it can also be shown that 
$$
\big\lVert T \big\rVert_{B(X, Y)} = \sup \left\{ \, \big\lVert T(x) \big\rVert_Y \, \colon \, x \in X, \lVert x \rVert_X = 1 \, \right\}. \tag{Formula II for Norm}
$$

If $S, T \in B(X, Y)$, then using (Norm Inequality) and the same procedure as used for deriving (1) above, we obtain 
$$
\big\lVert S +_{\mbox{ Hom }(X, Y)} T \big\rVert_{B(X, Y)} \leq \big\lVert S \big\rVert_{B(X, Y)} + \big\lVert T \big\rVert_{B(X, Y)}.
$$

And, if $T \in B(X, Y)$ and $\alpha$ is a scalar, then we can use the procedure adopted for deriving (2) above along with (Norm Inequality) above to obtain
$$
\big\lVert \alpha T \big\rVert_{B(X, Y)} = \lvert \alpha \rvert \, \big\lVert T \big\rVert_{B(X, Y)}. 
$$

Thus if $X$ and $Y$ are any normed spaces, either both real or both complex, then the set $B(X, Y)$ of all the bounded linear operaotrs $T \colon X \rightarrow Y$ is also a normed space with the norm defined by (Formula for Norm) or (Formula II for Norm) above.

Please also refer to Sec. 2.7 in the book *Introductory Functional Analysis With Applications* by Erwine Kreyszig.